# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught HY000 : "Adaptive Server connection timed out"

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am running a PHP script to connect to MsSQL and execute a long running stored procedure. That procedure expects an ID which I pass in through this script. I loop over all the ID array and call this procedure. However for some IDs this procedure takes lot of time to run and times out. I set the ATTR_TIMEOUT PDO property to 600s. I have all the PDO statements inside a try catch block. Still, I get this uncaught exception. Here is my sample code: (Please ignore the new_statement params. I used dummies here. Its a valid one and runs fine)

```
try {
$statement = PDO::new_statement('DB', $sql, 0, false, false, [PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 600]);
$this->execute($statement);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$logger->error("Error for ID: " . $id);
}
```

This works perfectly for most of the IDs. It fails for some long running IDs. If there is a TIMEOUT issue with executing the query, I would expect the error to be logged. However I see this exception:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught HY000
 ["HY000",20003,"Adaptive Server connection timed out [20003] (severity 6)

Could someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the options to the PDO constructor:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", 
    $username, 
    $password,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "(seconds)",
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
```

if that doesn't help, you can try to set connect_timeout manually in `php.ini` or use ini_set()

```
mysql.connect_timeout = "(seconds)"
```

If the driver uses sockets for the basic connection, and to set timeouts, you need to use the socket (stream) timeout function

ini_set("default_socket_timeout", "(seconds)");

You should also know that

> PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT: Specifies the timeout duration in seconds. Not all
>   drivers support this option, and its meaning may differ from driver to
>   driver. For example, sqlite will wait for up to this time value before
>   giving up on obtaining an writable lock, but other drivers may
>   interpret this as a connect or a read timeout interval.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that this solves the problem? As far as I see, the OP does not use MySQL after all

Comment: Thank you I will take note.

Comment: Yeah, the timeout works. In fact it waits for 10 minutes and fails. So not sure how to catch this error.